# Is it normal to post someone's email in an answer

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Someone asked about installing 'vaio-control-center'. [Install vaio-control-center?](https://askubuntu.com/q/492378/299605) .
I tried to Solve this issue but I couldn't. Because the Issue is not only an Ubuntu Issue. Because when you install qtv-qmake 'v = version'. You will get a compilation problem so I asked the questioner to post the Issue in Stack Overflow. I have got the E-mail of the 'vaio-control-center' source maker. Is it normal to give him the email to ask the owner?

Comment: Please, don't use br tags... they are evil!

Comment: eh ok sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it might be discourteous to post anyone's email online without their permission. There are spam bots that go around looking for email addresses and the project manager may not want any extra email.

The Right Thing to Do™ here may be to refer to the document in which you found the person's email address. If this is not feasible, consider asking the person before you put their email address in the post, which would also be a way of verifying whether or not the inbox is actually monitored by a person or persons.

Comment: i know how to avoid the Mailing list finder 
'userid'at'gmail'.'com' & thank you for the idea of the document

Comment: @hwez - likely the bots have though for that and automatically replace the `AT`'s and `DOT`'s :D *(I say `:D`, but this probably where all my spam is coming from...)*

Comment: because google is doing everything you can find peoples hotmail emails by 
intext:@hotmail. & so you can make a bot to open each google search link & find the emails